# How to show the size of entire mongo db in MBs

Tags: meteor

I have a admin dashboard built in Meteor js, all I want is, to show the size of entire mongodb in one of the section (just the count in MBs). Mongodb may contain **N** collections, but I want a single figure that gives size of entire database.

Pure Mongo db has a facility to check it like `db.collection.stats(1024 * 1024);`. But my requirement is to show the entire mongodb size in meteor template. any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Mongo.Collection#rawDatabase()`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-rawDatabase) and [`Mongo.Collection#rawCollection()`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-rawCollection) to get the db and collection object respectively in Meteor:

```
const Test = new Mongo.Collection('test')

Test.rawCollection().stats().then(d => console.log(d))
Test.rawDatabase().stats().then(d => console.log(d))
```

Now to show these information in client, you could use Meteor methods or query then store in db.

**Update:**

To use with Meteor method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  getDbSize() {
    return Test.rawDatabase().stats()
  }
})
```

Comment: I actually know this. But I want the size of entire db and not individual collections.

Comment: Isn't `rawDatabase` what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will check and let you know!

Comment: above code works fine but the problem is that I need to return the value from it. how to do it? i am new to Promises & ES6.

Comment: Meteor method and promise play nicely together, I updated the answer to include some code. Hope it helps